# Statistical test - Time-series - Marketing

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, t-test, autocorrelation

I want to compare to see if there is a statistically significant difference
between the mean of times-series A and time-series B.
Each time series represent the amount of daily revenue for each campaign. Both campaigns are targeting a different list of users. Each user can be in one of the lists but not in another.
Both time series have lag 1 autocorrelation of  > 0.5, so it seems t-test should not be used here.
Is there a statistical test I can use to compare the means of the groups?[image]

Comment: Have you considered a $t$-test where the estimate of the standard error is HAC robust rather than vanilla?

Comment: I haven't heard about HAC robust before. Will it allow me to use t-test without violating the iid assumption?

Comment: Yes, I think it should. It gives an estimate of the standard error that is valid under autocorrelation, unlike the vanilla estimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $t$-test assesses how big the difference in means are relative to the estimation precision. The latter is characterized by the standard error of the mean. In absence of autocorrelation, it is the standard deviation of the sample divided by $\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is the sample size. In presence of autocorrelation, the usual estimate is biased and invalid. A remedy is to use autocorrelation-robust, or HAC, standard error. It accounts for the bias due to autocorrelation and delivers a valid estimate of precision. This is the only modification needed to make your $t$-test valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that HAC is used mainly for estimating the SE of the Beta coefficient in regression models. I can't find a way how to apply to my t-test

Comment: @Paradox_spar, the relevant keyword may be "long-run variance". In R, there are many functions and packages for obtaining it. One of them is [`lrvar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sandwich/versions/3.0-1/topics/lrvar) from the `sandwich` package. You take the square root to obtain the standard error. It is as simple as that.

Comment: It seems the SE is a little bit larger than the vanilla SE when I use prewhite = TRUE, but smaller when I use prewhite = FALSE. The intuition says that the Hac SE should be larger than vanilla with time-series data, but I'm not sure if to use TRUE or FALSE and why

Comment: They are not always larger, you could construct examples where they are smaller. The question of prewhitening is quite tough. There are some recommendations depending on whether you care more about the size of the test or its power (see papers: Andrews 1991, Andrews & Monahan 1992 – you should find them easily just by names and years in Google Scholar), but ultimately it boils down to what the underlying data generating process actually is, and we never know that... So no simple and nice answer to your question, unfortunately (though you can still use their recommendations).

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot!

Comment: @Yevs, I am glad I was able to!

Answer (score 0):

When two campaigns' values follow the same trend through time,  their difference through time should be just noise with no trend; this defined as an ARIMA (0,0,0,0) model.

When we apply ARIMA modeling to Campaign A -Campaign B  we have the best model (using R function auto.arima) is ARIMA(0,0,0,0) with mean 21.0. Hence, we have noise with no trend or autocorrelation close to zero.

Then, we can use the standard T test for the difference  Campaign A -Campaign B; for your dataset we get t = 2.4592, df = 19, p-value = 0.02369 and mean difference is 21.05

When the difference is not white noise, then, mostlikely will change through time.